# Calling a function on assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variable-assignment

I'm pretty sure this is impossible but maybe someone clever out there knows if there is a chance of making this work. Is it possible to have code where:

```
1    myPerson = new Person();
2    myPerson.name = 'Charles Xavier';
```

Where the code on line #2 automatically checks if myPerson.setName exists and if so calls

```
myPerson.setName('Charles Xavier');
```

in place of of doing the direct assignment.

Comment: Create a helper function which does the check for you? Or why dont you do the check inside `setName()`?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, sorry! It is possible in ES6, though:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "name", {
  set: function (value) {
    console.log("Property 'name' set to: " + value);
    // store 'value' somewhere
  }
});
```

c.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Since this is not possible in < ES6, frameworks like AngularJS use dirty-checking (aka they check the value X times per second) to watch for property changes.

Comment: Dirty checking sounds terrible! Very cool that this type of functionality is coming with ES6 though.

Comment: @Kirk haha it does sound terrible but it works pretty well for AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Not for all browser, but there's [javascript proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which is only work on firefox, and make this become useless. :D

```
var Validator = {
    set: function(obj, prop, value){
        if(prop == 'name' && setName in obj)
            obj.setName(value);

        obj[prop] = value;
    }
}

var myPerson = new Proxy(Person, Validator);
myPerson.name = 'Charles Xavier'; // This will call Validator.set
```